# Make click available only when function is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a jquery function which validates values, edit a hidden form and hide/show divs depending on a value. Similar as add/remove items to a shop basket. This works fine when the user clicks with normal speed.

However when the user clicks very fast, things go wrong. Adding products to the basket and validating are mixing up, whinch leads to strangs results.

How do I disable clicking while a function is executing?

I just call the add function with a normal click function:

```
$('.add').click(add);
```

Comment: The browser only processes one event at a time. You'll have to post more of your code in order for people to see what's going on.

Comment: Make sure events are `a·syn·chro·nous`, then.

Comment: `asynchronous` not asynchrous -_- Ah ah ok, you corrected it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".add").bind('click', function(){
    console.log('bound');
});

$(".add").unbind('click');
```

use bind and unbind functions

Comment: I used the newer .on() and .off() functions, but the idea is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the button or hyperlink after click and re-enable when the function is done either directly or with a callback:

```
$(".add").click(add);

function add(event) {
   $(".add").attr({disabled: "disabled"});
   // .... some code
   $(".add").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

However, the property `disabled` may not work the same in every browser; it might only work for form elements and not hyperlinks (`a`) for instance.

Another solution would be to throttle your event handler, for instance using [UnderscoreJS's throttle method](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution but you have to use button.

```
var buttons = $(".add");
buttons.click( function(){
    buttons.attr("disabled","disabled");
    //Do your job and don't forget to remove 'disabled'
});
```